# Using destructuring assignment and the rest syntax for default variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following is an attempt to set the default value for an argument, based on the first argument:

```js
function tree(values, ...[[curr] = values]) {
    console.log(curr);
}
    
tree(['foo']); // foo
tree(['foo'], ['bar']); // bar
```

It appears to work (actually it isn't *quite* what I want, but I want to understand this first).

What is going on here?

Comment: It’s equivalent to `function tree(values, [curr] = values)`, if that helps.

Comment: `function foo (...[bar])` is equivalent to `function foo(bar)`.

Comment: FYI this is all "rest" syntax, not "spread". Rest creates an array, spread takes an iterable and uses it for something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The spread syntax is spreading an anonymous array with the contents of curr…

No. Nothing is being spreaded into an array literal.

> The spread syntax is capturing the rest of the arguments into an anonymous array instance which is being destructured…

Yes.

> …into the first value of either: the supplied array if present, or values.

Not sure I understand. The captured array is destructured to the target `[[curr] = values]`, which takes out the first element or - if not present - the `values` default, and assigns that to the target `[curr]`.

And as @FelixKling commented, you really should not do that, but use

```
function tree(values, [curr] = values) {
    console.log(curr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I had this weird outer "use the rest syntax to capture an anonymous array for destructuring" is that the final syntax I wanted was `function tree(values, ...[[curr, ...rest] = values]) { }` so that I could capture the rest of `values`.

Comment: Again, `function tree(values, [curr, ...rest] = values) { … }`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because default parameters can reference previous parameters. In your example you are destructuring `values` to `curr`, that's why the console is printing the first element of the array. You could suppress the spread operator and the result would be the same:

```
function tree(values, [curr] = values) {
    console.log(curr);
}

tree(['foo']); // foo
tree(['foo'], ['bar']); // bar
```

What is happening to the second call `tree(['foo'], ['bar'])` is that the second argument (`['bar']`) is overriding `[curr]` default value.

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters (look for the section titled "Default parameters are available to later default parameters")